# "virtualenv-3.4" in Python 2.6?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I just installed Python 2.6.9 from source.  The first thing I did was install pip, then execute "pip install virtualenv".  I'd like to know why this created a "virtualenv" AND "virtualenv-3.4" in my 2.6 bin directory.

Here's the output of the pip install:

```
  Downloading virtualenv-12.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.6MB 145kB/s 
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv-12.1.1
```

I tested it out and both "virtualenv" and "virtualenv-3.4" do the same thing (create a new environment with Python 2.6).  The naming of "virtualenv-3.4" is misleading and seemingly superfluous.  Or am I missing something?

Python 3.4 is not installed and there's no reason I can see why or how the installer would have thought to associate virtualenv with the suffix "3.4".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like virtualenv has one universal unstaller for both py2 and py3.

> Downloading virtualenv-12.1.1-**py2.py3**-none-any.whl

So you don't have to install two packages if you have both Python versions installed.